# Rspec and Infinity Test in color

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

I am using infinity_test gem with rspec in a rails project. How can I get the output in color? I tried setting in terminal

```
rspec --color
```

I then ran "rspec spec/" to make sure color output was working. Then I run

```
infinity_test
```

and the test output is no longer in color. How can I get it to output in color?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This a bug in the InfinityTest.

There is a issue in Github.

It's a very strange bug, and don't find where the problem occurs. I think in the lib/infinity_test/command.rb#line 21 is the problem.

I'll try to solve the problem, but patches are welcome!

Sorry for that, but thanks for the info. =]

Comment: Tomas! Thank you for the awesome infinity_test! I'll try taking a look as well but as a rookie ruby/rails dev I'm not sure how much progress I'll make. And just so you know I'm using rspec 2.0

Comment: W00t! I'm glad that you're using InfinityTest =]

Comment: The information about the RSpec colors is in the Readme of InfinityTest now. =)

Answer (score 0):

Just create a spec/.spec file in your spec directory. The file should look like this:

```
--color [+Other options you want to pass to rspec]
```

Comment: This doesn't work for me. I also tried to put the --color option in a spec/spec.opts file but that doesn't work either.

Comment: I do have a .rspec file with the --color option in my project root. But when I run infinity_test it doesn't show up in color.

Comment: Do you have a .infinity_test file in place. Try putting the .rspec file in your user's home directory; ~/.rspec?